# Unable to nullify a custom field

Tags: database, quote, mysql-triggers

There is a custom extension that manage the shipping address for a local shipping carriers. Besides some extra fields for local data there is a custom field called `tipo_direccion` (address type in spanish) that holds just one value: 1 (for the office address of some shipping carrier) or NULL (for an specific shipping address). There's no other value for that field.

Now, in the `config.xml`, the text of the `address_templates` has a condition asking if `tipo_direccion` is set, if is true it will display the shipping carrier office address, but if it's not then it will display the particular shipping address. Once again, as the `tipo_direccion` never is null then the specific shipping address is never displayed.

I tried with jQuery (in the `checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml` template), PHP (in `Checkout/controllers/OnePageController.php`) and finally as a MySQL trigger (attached to `sales_flat_quote_address` table). Nothing seems to work (the trigger works perfectly in a testing database but not in the Magento database).

Here is the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER fix_quote_address 
BEFORE INSERT ON sales_flat_quote_address
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.tipo_direccion = 0 THEN 
        SET NEW.tipo_direccion = NULL;
    END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT: here is the `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <!-- modules -->  
    <admin>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <!-- *** -->
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <models>
            <!-- *** -->
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <!-- *** -->
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <!-- *** -->
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <!-- *** -->
        </resources>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <!-- *** -->                
            </customer_account>      
            <sales_copy_order_billing_address>
                <!-- *** -->
                <tipo_direccion>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </tipo_direccion>
                <!-- *** -->
            </sales_copy_order_billing_address>
            <sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
                <!-- *** -->
                <tipo_direccion>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </tipo_direccion>
                <!-- *** -->
            </sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <!-- *** -->      
                <tipo_direccion>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                    <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
                </tipo_direccion>
                <!-- *** -->
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
            <sales_convert_order_address>
                <!-- *** -->
                <tipo_direccion>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </tipo_direccion>
                <!-- *** -->
            </sales_convert_order_address>
            <customer_address>
                <!-- *** -->
                <tipo_direccion>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </tipo_direccion>
                <!-- *** -->
            </customer_address>
            <checkout_onepage_billing>
                <!-- *** -->
            </checkout_onepage_billing>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <!-- *** -->
    </frontend>

    <default>
        <carriers>
            <!-- *** -->
        </carriers>
        <customer>
            <address_templates>
                <text>
                    {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}}{{/depend}}
                    {{var firstname}}{{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}}{{/depend}}
                    {{var lastname}}
                    {{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend tipo_nif}}{{var tipo_nif}}{{var codigo_nif}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
                    {{if tipo_direccion}}
                        {{depend nombre_estado}}{{var nombre_estado}}, {{/depend}}
                        {{depend ciudad}}{{var nombre_ciudad}}, {{/depend}}
                        {{depend nombre_oficina}}{{var nombre_oficina}}, {{/depend}}
                        {{depend nombre_responsable}}{{var nombre_responsable}}, {{/depend}}
                        {{depend cedula_responsable}}{{var cedula_responsable}}{{/depend}}
                    {{else}}
                        {{var nombre_direccion}}
                        {{depend street1}}{{var street1}}{{/depend}}
                        {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
                        {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
                        {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
                        {{depend city}}{{var city}}, {{/depend}}
                        {{depend region}}{{var region}}, {{/depend}}
                        {{depend postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/depend}}
                        {{var country}}
                        {{depend ekl_municipio}}{{var ekl_municipio}}, 
                        {{var ekl_parroquia}}{{/depend}}
                        T1: {{var local_phone_cod}}-{{var local_phone_num}}
                        T2: {{var cellular_cod}}-{{var cellular_num}}
                        {{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
                        {{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
                    {{/if}}
                </text>
                <oneline>
                    <!-- *** -->
                </oneline>
                <html>
                    <!-- *** -->
                </html>
                <pdf>
                    <!-- *** -->
                </pdf>
                <js_template>
                    <!-- *** -->
                </js_template>
            </address_templates>
        </customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Please post related config.xml code. Better to handle via Magento itself than to have trigger for this.

Comment: @Kalpesh done, check it out.

Comment: You said `tipo_direccion` is a custom field from custom extension. Can't you change the logic in that extension itself? Also does it work as expected if `tipo_direccion` is set to NULL instead of 0?

Comment: @Kalpesh: I guess I could do that, but I'd rather don't do it. Yes, if I change (on database) all the records with `tipo_direccion` from `0` to `NULL`, all the shipping address are displayed as they should.

Comment: Can you try `{{if customer.getTipoDireccion()}}` instead of `{{if tipo_direccion}}`?

Comment: @Kalpesh: I've noticing that Magento is ignoring that `config.xml`. All the templates addresses are read from the `core_config_data`. All the modifications made to that file are worthless. All the modifications made to the field `value` where the field `path` is setted to `customer/address_templates/html`, works. But I still can't find a proper form to modify those address templates. According to the user manual the path is: `Admin menu > System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration`.

Comment: @Kalpesh: Finally!!! it worked!, `customer.getTipoDireccion()` works perfect!. Very funny, I just tried that this morning, but I made the change in the `config.xml` template, which Magento is ignoring. I was experimenting with some examples I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797394/magento-email-template-if-statements

Comment: Glad to hear. I know Magento reads config.xml for setting default values first time only when module is registered/updated, not sure why didn't noticed in your question, my bad. I am posting this as answer it can help other developers stuck in similar situation.

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to know where in the Admin Panel is that edition form. I'm modifying the template using an update SQL statement, is really annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `{{if tipo_direccion}}` to `{{if customer.getTipoDireccion()}}` worked for OP.

Also the change was done in `core_config_data` table where all the Magento configuration resides. If your module is not already registered, you can do this change in `config.xml` file but if the module is already registered (in `core_resource` table there will be an entry) then you have to modify it in `core_config_data` table (be careful!).